# How to get the whole object whose value is bound to multiple inputs when one of the input is changed?

Tags: reactjs

Assume I have a following object

```
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'abc',
  subs: [{
    s1: 's1'
    s2: 's2'
  }, {
    s1: 's3'
    s2: 's4'
  }]
}
```

I have bound obj.a , obj.b, obj.subs[0].s1, obj.subs[0].s2, obj.subs[1].s1, obj.subs[1].s2 to inputs.

How can I get the obj with the mutated value when either any of the above inputs is changed?

e.g.
when obj.subs[1].s1 is changed, how to get the object instance whose "subs[1].s1" property is changed.

Comment: Do you have an example of your app structure?

Comment: Your question is not clear. In react all the **"bounds"** go to through the state. So I'm guessing you have something like: `this.state = {a:1,sub:[{s1:'s1'}]}`, if one input has changed you have to modify the state.